# Find all possible injective mappings of 2 vectors

Tags: matlab

I have 2 vectors:

```
A = [1 2]
B = [3 4 5]
```

I want to find all different mappings between A and B that are injective, i.e., the result should be something like that:

```
1 3     1 4     1 5     1 3     1 4     1 5
2 4     2 3     2 3     2 5     2 5     2 4
  5       5       4       4       3       3
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how to do this in MATLAB? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to compute all *permutations* of the range vector `B`:

```
perms(B).'
```

This will give the second columns of your desired results. The first column is just your domain vector transposed, `A.'`

---

To store the mappings you could just keep the *n* first rows of each second column, where *n* is the length of `A`. Since there may be repetitions, you remove them with `unique`;

```
aux = perms(B);
mappings = unique(aux(:,1:length(A)),'rows').';
```

So, `mappings(i,j)` is the image of the *i*-th element of `A` through the *j*-th mapping.

---

To display the result in the format you posted, you only need to play with `reshape` a bit to interleave domain and ranges of the mappings:

```
>> reshape([repmat(A.',1,size(mappings,2)); mappings],length(A),[])

ans =
     1     5     1     5     1     4     1     4     1     3     1     3
     2     4     2     3     2     5     2     3     2     4     2     5
```

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. How do you manipulate the result such that only different answers are considered? Imagine A = [1 2] and B = [3 4 5 6]. Then your approach procudes the same vector multiple times: [1 2],[5 6]; [1 2],[5,6]; ... In other words: I want to filter out those mappings that are unique.

Comment: @tw-S Well seen, I hadn't thought of that. You do that with `unique`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, this yields an error: Error using unique (line 106)
Invalid input. Valid flags are 'rows', 'first', 'last', 'stable', 'sorted', 'legacy', 'R2012a'.

Error in alloc2 (line 9)
mappings = unique(:,aux(1:length(sp_cost)),'rows').'

Comment: @tw-S Try now. I've been doing several edits, you may have seen an intermediate edit

Comment: Strange, with A = [1 2], B = [2 3 4 5 6], I am getting:
mappings = [3 4]  ,  [4 3] ,   [5  5] ,  [6  6] ,  [7 7]. That's not right, isn't it?

Comment: @tw-S With those `A` and `B` I get a `mappings` variable with 20 columns, which seems to be correct: [2 3], [2 4], [2 5]... Have you tried the current version of the answer? Please copy the code again from the answer and try.